# Strange start error updating to Mojarra 2.2.6

Tags: jsf-2, tomcat7, mojarra

I've updated Mojarra 2.2.5 to 2.2.6 on a Tomcat 7.0.42 + jdk1.6.0_27 system and, on startup, I experienced the folloging error (... even if the application starts and works correctly) :

```
SEVERE: Unable to find the encoded key.
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jsf/ClientSideSecretKey] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jsf].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:158)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard.setupKeyAndMac(ByteArrayGuard.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard.<init>(ByteArrayGuard.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.init(ClientSideStateHelper.java:476)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.<init>(ClientSideStateHelper.java:150)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.<init>(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:68)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.<init>(RenderKitImpl.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitFactoryImpl.<init>(RenderKitFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinder.java:721)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinder.java:553)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.access$500(FactoryFinder.java:140)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1120)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:435)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4937)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
SecretKey: 31chBtWqlcPEsnTy/BVEOA==Mar 31, 2014 7:20:48 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
```

Any suggestion ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

The same thing happened to me. Apparently if the view state saving method is configured as "client" the hidden view state is encrypted, and the key used to encrypt it can be supplied (optionally) using the "jsf/ClientSideSecretKey" environment variable. By trial-and-error I've found out that the key has to be Base64 encoded.

After adding this to my web.xml file...

```
<env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>jsf/ClientSideSecretKey</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
   <env-entry-value>am9kZXRlcHV0b2hhY2tlcg==</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

the error disappeared.

What I would **really** want to know is... Where is this feature documented? The only information I could find is here: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3083

Comment: This works for me, however, at first I was getting `InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 50 bytes`. Eventually found out that the key can only be 8, 16 or 32 bytes long (prior to BASE64 encoding). I then changed it to 32 and instead got the exception `InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size`. Turned out that to use a 32 bytes long key, you need Java Cryptography Extension, which is available here: [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)